# Sequelize group by and subquery false query count is wrong and not include many element only one

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I try to get all products and all associated classes from db. I all get the products and associated elements but where many to many association occur there is one model came as associated include. belongs to many and many to many is in same situation. I need to use subquery false because limit doesnt work with it. Meanwhile, removing group by returns with wrong count and rows.

```
let confs = await Modelx.findAndCountAll({
    where: mapx.size == 0 ? null : mapx,
    attributes: [
      "id",
      "name",
      "CategoryId",
      "BrandId",

      [db.sequelize.col("ProductPhotos.path"), "path"],
      [db.sequelize.col("ProductPrices.price"), "price"],

      [
        db.sequelize.fn("SUM", db.sequelize.col("ProductStorages.qty")),
        "total_amount",
      ],
    ],
    include: [
      {
        model: db.productDescription,
      },
      {
        model: db.categories,
        attributes: [],
      },
      {
        model: db.productBrand,
        attributes: [],
      },
      {
        model: db.productPhoto,
        attributes: [],
      },
      {
        model: db.productPrice,
        attributes: [],
      },

      {
        model: db.productDiscount,

        through: { attributes: [] },
      },
      {
        model: db.productStorage,
      },
    ],

    group: [
      "Products.id",
      //"ProductStorages.createdAt",
      // "ProductPhotos.id",
      //"ProductDiscounts.createdAt",
      // "ProductPrices.id",
    ],

    having: req.havings,
   subQuery: false,

    order: req.orderx,
    limit: req.size,
    offset: req.page * req.size,
  });
```

Sequelize log;

```
Executing (default): SELECT count(`Products`.`id`) AS `count` FROM `Products` AS `Products` LEFT OUTER JOIN `ProductDescriptions` AS `ProductDescription` ON `Products`.`id` = `ProductDescription`.`ProductId` LEFT OUTER JOIN `Categories` AS `Category` ON `Products`.`CategoryId` = `Category`.`id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `Brands` AS `Brand` ON `Products`.`ProductBrandId` = `Brand`.`id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `ProductPhotos` AS `ProductPhotos` ON `Products`.`id` = `ProductPhotos`.`ProductId` LEFT OUTER JOIN `ProductPrices` AS `ProductPrices` ON `Products`.`id` = `ProductPrices`.`ProductId` LEFT OUTER JOIN ( `ProductDiscountsThrogs` AS `ProductDiscounts->ProductDiscountsThrogs` INNER JOIN `ProductDiscounts` AS `ProductDiscounts` ON `ProductDiscounts`.`id` = `ProductDiscounts->ProductDiscountsThrogs`.`ProductDiscountId`) ON `Products`.`id` = `ProductDiscounts->ProductDiscountsThrogs`.`ProductId` LEFT OUTER JOIN `ProductStorages` AS `ProductStorages` ON `Products`.`id` = `ProductStorages`.`ProductId`;
Executing (default): SELECT `Products`.`id`, `Products`.`name`, `Products`.`CategoryId`, `Products`.`BrandId`, `ProductPhotos`.`path` AS `path`, `ProductPrices`.`price` AS `price`, SUM(`ProductStorages`.`qty`) AS `total_amount`, `ProductDescription`.`id` AS `ProductDescription.id`, `ProductDescription`.`name` AS `ProductDescription.name`, `ProductDescription`.`is_checked` AS `ProductDescription.is_checked`, `ProductDescription`.`ProductId` AS `ProductDescription.ProductId`, `ProductDescription`.`createdAt` AS `ProductDescription.createdAt`, `ProductDescription`.`updatedAt` AS `ProductDescription.updatedAt`, `ProductDiscounts`.`id` AS `ProductDiscounts.id`, `ProductDiscounts`.`discount_value` AS `ProductDiscounts.discount_value`, `ProductDiscounts`.`discount_type` AS `ProductDiscounts.discount_type`, `ProductDiscounts`.`is_checked` AS `ProductDiscounts.is_checked`, `ProductDiscounts`.`is_live` AS `ProductDiscounts.is_live`, `ProductDiscounts`.`endAt` AS `ProductDiscounts.endAt`, `ProductDiscounts`.`createdAt` AS `ProductDiscounts.createdAt`, `ProductDiscounts`.`updatedAt` AS `ProductDiscounts.updatedAt`, `ProductStorages`.`id` AS `ProductStorages.id`, `ProductStorages`.`qty` AS `ProductStorages.qty`, `ProductStorages`.`is_checked` AS `ProductStorages.is_checked`, `ProductStorages`.`ProductId` AS `ProductStorages.ProductId`, `ProductStorages`.`BrandId` AS `ProductStorages.BrandId`, `ProductStorages`.`ProductPriceId` AS `ProductStorages.ProductPriceId`, `ProductStorages`.`type` AS `ProductStorages.type`, `ProductStorages`.`createdAt` AS `ProductStorages.createdAt`, `ProductStorages`.`updatedAt` AS `ProductStorages.updatedAt` FROM `Products` AS `Products` LEFT OUTER JOIN `ProductDescriptions` AS `ProductDescription` ON `Products`.`id` = `ProductDescription`.`ProductId` LEFT OUTER JOIN `Categories` AS `Category` ON `Products`.`CategoryId` = `Category`.`id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `Brands` AS `Brand` ON `Products`.`ProductBrandId` = `Brand`.`id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `ProductPhotos` AS `ProductPhotos` ON `Products`.`id` = `ProductPhotos`.`ProductId` LEFT OUTER JOIN `ProductPrices` AS `ProductPrices` ON `Products`.`id` = `ProductPrices`.`ProductId` LEFT OUTER JOIN ( `ProductDiscountsThrogs` AS `ProductDiscounts->ProductDiscountsThrogs` INNER JOIN `ProductDiscounts` AS `ProductDiscounts` ON `ProductDiscounts`.`id` = `ProductDiscounts->ProductDiscountsThrogs`.`ProductDiscountId`) ON `Products`.`id` = `ProductDiscounts->ProductDiscountsThrogs`.`ProductId` LEFT OUTER JOIN `ProductStorages` AS `ProductStorages` ON `Products`.`id` = `ProductStorages`.`ProductId`;
```

I need to get all expected rows and count correctly with all associated elements included.